# stop Vimeo iframe + jQuery Cycle plugin

Tags: jquery, iframe, cycle, vimeo

Although I'm quite accomplished in other fields, I'm a complete noob when it comes to programming anything (please don't hate me too much for it). I'm designing a simple website with a next/previous button slideshow using the jQuery Cycle plugin (from http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/). Here's my javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#Slider').cycle({
        fx:     'scrollHorz',// choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
        speed:  600, 
        timeout: 0, 
        easing: 'easeInOutBack',
        after:   onAfter,
        next:   '#Next',
        prev:   '#Previous',
    });
    $(function() {
    $('td pre code').each(function() {
    eval($(this).text());
    });
});
function onAfter(curr, next, opts) {
    var index = opts.currSlide;
    $('#Previous')[index == 0 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
    $('#Next')[index == opts.slideCount - 1 ? 'hide' : 'show']();
    }
});
```

The slideshow, which has images and iframe vimeo clips, works perfectly fine EXCEPT for when I click the Previous/Next button and the vimeo video doesn't stop (but continues on in the background when I watch the next slide). I've read in other posts that I'm supposed to incorporate a window.postmessage command but I have no clue on how to go about this. Where and how in my above code would I insert a command to stop my vimeo video from playing when I press Previous/Next??